# How to make an array of React Native components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-table

I'm trying use a `react-native-table-component` in my view ([docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-table-component)), but I'm running into an issue because I want my column to have image components. I followed the example in the docs that uses buttons, and have something like this:

```
    console.log("following pic arr: " + this.state.followingPics);
    var following_pics;
    if(this.state.followingPics.length === 0) {
        following_pics = [];
    }
    else {
        //this.state.followingPics is an array of picture urls
        JSON.parse(this.state.followingPics).forEach((pic, i) => {
            following_pics.push(makeImage(pic));
        })
    }

    var tableArr = [following_pics, following];

    return (
        <View style={shared.basicView}>
            <TextInput
                autoCorrect={false}
                style={{height: 40}}
                placeholder="Follow a user..."
                onSubmitEditing={(input) => this.addFollower(input.nativeEvent.text)}
            />
            <Table style={styles.table}
                   borderStyle={{borderWidth: 0.5, borderColor: '#c8e1ff'}}>
                <Row data={tableHead}
                     style={styles.head} textStyle={styles.text}
                     flexArr={[1]}
                />
                <Cols data={tableArr}
                      textStyle={styles.text}
                      heightArr={[50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50]}
                      flexArr={[1, 2, 1, 2]}
                />
            </Table>
        </View>
    );
```

But I keep getting an error saying `undefined is not an object (evaluating following_pics.push)`. Is there any way I can add these pictures as a data array like specified?

Comment: You have hit the `else` part of your if statement (line 6 of your first snippet), at which point the variable is undefined. Instantiate your variable like so `var following_pics = []`.

Comment: Oh wow, extremely silly mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you do in your `else` block is you trying to `push` elements to undefined variable:

```
console.log("following pic arr: " + this.state.followingPics);
var following_pics;  // this will be undefined in else block
if(this.state.followingPics.length === 0) {
    following_pics = [];
}
else {
    //this.state.followingPics is an array of picture urls
    JSON.parse(this.state.followingPics).forEach((pic, i) => {
        following_pics.push(makeImage(pic));
    })
}
```

I don understand why you need this if block, why not just:

```
console.log("following pic arr: " + this.state.followingPics);
var following_pics = [];
//this.state.followingPics is an array of picture urls
JSON.parse(this.state.followingPics).forEach((pic, i) => {
   following_pics.push(makeImage(pic));
})
```